# ANTLR4: Unable to match INT and BOOLEAN

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I have written the following grammar to compute combination of logical and relational operators in Java.

In the grammar, I am able to use Equals opertor(`=`) only for **STRING** type and not for **INT** and **BOOLEAN** types. Can someone please help me identify what is wrong?

I am able to `("a" == "b")` and not able to `("a" == 567)`. Left hand operand is variable and I will substitute the values during runtime.

```
grammar testGrammar;

/*
 * Parser rules
 */

conditionalExpression: leftOperand=conditionalExpression operator=LOGICAL_OPERATORS rightOperand=conditionalExpression #LogicalOperators
| '(' conditionalExpression ')' #ParenthesisExpression
| leftOperand=STRING operator=BOOLEAN_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS rightOperand=BOOLEAN #RelationalBooleanOperators
| leftOperand=STRING operator=STRING_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS rightOperand=STRING #RelationalStringOperators
| leftOperand=STRING operator=INT_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS rightOperand=INT #RelationalIntOperators
;

/*
 * Lexer rules
 */
STRING: '"'CHAR(CHAR)*'"';
INT:DIGIT+;
BOOLEAN: BOOLEAN_TRUE | BOOLEAN_FALSE;
LOGICAL_OPERATORS: LOGICAL_OR | LOGICAL_AND | LOGICAL_NOT;

STRING_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS: RELATIONAL_EQUALS | RELATIONAL_NOT_EQUAL;

INT_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS: RELATIONAL_EQUALS | RELATIONAL_NOT_EQUAL | RELATIONAL_GREATER_THEN
| RELATIONAL_GREATER_THEN_OR_EQUAL | RELATIONAL_LESS_THEN | RELATIONAL_LESS_THEN_OR_EQUAL;

BOOLEAN_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS: RELATIONAL_EQUALS | RELATIONAL_NOT_EQUAL;

fragment RELATIONAL_EQUALS: '==';
fragment RELATIONAL_NOT_EQUAL: '!=';
fragment RELATIONAL_GREATER_THEN: '>';
fragment RELATIONAL_LESS_THEN: '<';
fragment RELATIONAL_GREATER_THEN_OR_EQUAL: '>=';
fragment RELATIONAL_LESS_THEN_OR_EQUAL: '<=';

fragment LOGICAL_AND: '&&';
fragment LOGICAL_OR: '||';
fragment LOGICAL_NOT: '!';

fragment CHAR: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

fragment BOOLEAN_TRUE: 'true';
fragment BOOLEAN_FALSE: 'false';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple lexer rules that would match the input `==` or `!=`. ANTLR (as well as most lexer generators) resolves ambiguities in lexer rules by first picking the one(s) that produce the longest match (in this case all the rules would produce a match of length 2) and then resolving ties by picking the one that comes first in the grammar. So when the lexer sees a `==` or `!=`, it will always generate a token of type `STRING_RELATIONAL_OPERATORS`.

Note that the lexer does not care which tokens the parser wants right now - the lexer functions independently from the parser. It only looks at the current input and the defined lexer rules to decide which kind of token to create. So the same sequence of characters will always create the same kind of token.

To fix your grammar, you should define your lexer rules, so that they do not overlap and then group them as you like in parser rules. So you could have one lexer rule per operator (perhaps implicitly by using string literals in parser rules) and then simply use `('==' | '!=' | ...)` in the parser.

I would also recommend to just have a single parser rule for relational expressions. Right now you have one per type to disallow comparing expressions of different types, but this approach does not scale (what are you going to do when you introduce variables, for example?). Instead you should simply allow ill-typed expression in the parser and then reject them in the type checker that you write separately.

PS: In order to find these types of issues in the lexer, it helps to print the token stream that has been generated for a given input. You can achieve that by iterating over the token stream in your Java code or by running `grun YourGrammarName tokens -tokens yourInputFile` in the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) In my case, I don't know the data type of variable and therefore couldn't find the right operator. Whether there is no way to re-use same operator for different data types?

Comment: @KrishnaM Just have a single rule `operand relationalOperator operand` where `relationalOperator` matches all relational operators and `operand` matches all possible operands regardless of type. Then let the type checker worry about the rest.

Comment: If we bring in type checker, then we need maintain a map of type of the variable right? In my case, the left hand operand will be the variable.

Comment: @KrishnaM Once you introduce variables to your language, your type checker needs a map of variable names to types, yes.